# .NET 1.1 Windows service doesnt start due to leap year

Tags: windows-services

We have a few backend windows services written in .net framework 1.1 running and on December 31st 2008 around 5.00 pm (EST) we stopped these services to run some year end reports.After the reports were run , we tried to start the services and the moment we attempt , it would give an error "Service did not start in a timely fashion".We tried every possible things that google came up with.Service Packs , WinDbg , GFlags etc etc.

Finally we called in Microsoft support around 10.30pm(we had premium support contract with Microsoft) and they started collecting all kinds of server data and around 12.05 am (EST) the services starting successfully with no issues.We hadn't done anything different or special to get it started.The whole team was stumped as to what was happening and equally glad that it was working.

The conclusion is Microsoft support team thinks that this could very well be something to do with the .NET Framework 1.1 namepsace System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase inability to support leap year.They havent confirmed it yet and are still investigating.

I will keep posted as and when I have updates form MSFT support.I was planning for a dreadful 2009 start but gladly it all ended fine.

Comment: Wonder if this is why all those zunes died?

Comment: It is, http://www.zuneboards.com/forums/zune-news/38143-cause-zune-30-leapyear-problem-isolated.html

Comment: Yes, there is. And the answer is also given here.

Comment: If you've solved a tricky problem, then it could be considered a service to the SO community to describe the problem and then answer it. Probably best, though, to make your own answer community wiki.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the bug is related to the one that causes Zune 30GBs to lock up on 31 December in leap years: it tests for day>365 in one place and day>366 in another and as a result when day=366 it falls through the second test and goes in to an infinite loop.